# Terminology for sentence with heterographs that can be read at a different starting point with a different meaning?

Tags: terminology, homonyms

There's a song lyric that, when repeated, becomes a different sentence even though it's pronounced the same:

> You're worn out sole to heel

becomes

> To heal your worn-out soul

You're worn out sole to heel / you're worn out sole / to heal your worn-out soul

Is there a specific name for this kind of sentence where it completely changes meaning because of the heterographic homonyms?

Comment: I expect there's a relevant *data processing* term for "misparsing caused by choosing the wrong starting point in a repeating sequence", but I seriously doubt there'd be enough use for such a term in natural language processing. Particularly if we're talking about contexts involving repeated *sounds*, rather than the written form as such.

Comment: Hmm, I feel like maybe there's a puzzle type similar to this, but I'm not finding it. Maybe you could call it a homophonic ouroboros?